# Chef: Why am I not reading in the attribute value I just set?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am getting my toes wet with chef at my job and have been tasked with installing making a recipe to install telegraf on our machines with custom configs. Let me also preface this with I have no ruby experience.

Before downloading or installing telegraf I want to verify that the if telegraf exists to only do all the following work if the versions miss match.

So I have attempted to set an attribute during the recipe runtime that other resources will check against.

```
ruby_block 'get telegraf version' do
  block do
      #tricky way to load this Chef::Mixin::ShellOut utilities
      Chef::Resource::RubyBlock.send(:include, Chef::Mixin::ShellOut)
      command = 'C:\\Program Files\\telegraf\\telegraf.exe --version'
      command_out = shell_out(command)
      node.default['windows']['telegraf']['installed_version'] = 'good'
  end
  notifies :write, 'log[log_version]', :delayed
  action :run
  only_if { ::File.exists?('C:\\Program Files\\telegraf\\telegraf.exe')}
end

log 'log_version' do
    message node['windows']['telegraf']['installed_version']
    level :error
end
```

When I look at the output though I see

```
     * ruby_block[get telegraf version] action run[2018-07-23T14:48:11-07:00] INFO: Processing ruby_block[get telegraf version] action run (win-telegraf::telegraf line 26)
   [2018-07-23T14:48:11-07:00] INFO: ruby_block[get telegraf version] called

       - execute the ruby block get telegraf version
     * log[log_version] action write[2018-07-23T14:48:11-07:00] INFO: Processing log[log_version] action write (win-telegraf::telegraf line 39)
   [2018-07-23T14:48:11-07:00] ERROR:
```

So why is it when I read `node['windows']['telegraf']['installed_version']` that the log prints nothing instead of 'good'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chef uses a two-pass loading system, check out https://coderanger.net/two-pass/ for more details. But the tl;dr for this case is that the stuff inside `block do ... end` runs in the second phase, while the Ruby code for the `log` resource is evaluated in the first phase. In general you can fix this using the `lazy{}` helper, but in this case what you probably want is either a custom resource or an Ohai plugin. For "normal" Windows applications, this is all handled by the MSI subsystem and the `windows_package` resource, but as Telegraf doesn't offer MSI packages you are a bit out of luck. That said, there are packages available for Chocolatey (a Windows packaging system like Mac's Homebrew) so you might want to look into using that instead of writing this yourself.